# How to update a mutable reference to a noncopyable type?

Tags: reference, copy, rust, move, mutable

I want to do something like

```
impl Widget {
    fn foo(self, rhs: Widget) -> Self {
        // Some stuff
    }

    fn update(&mut self, rhs: Widget) {
        *self = (*self).foo(rhs)
    }
}
```

but the compiler complains "cannot move out of borrowed context."  What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the [`take_mut`](https://crates.io/crates/take_mut) crate, which offers the `take` functions that do exactly what you want:

> `take` allows for taking `T` out of a `&mut T`, doing anything with it including consuming it, and producing another `T` to put back in the `&mut T`.

As pointed by [Francis Gagné](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37636003/5189607), the problem of doing this is that the `&mut` reference will be in a invalid state if a panic happens, and this can lead to undefined behavior. The `take_mut` approach is:

> During `take`, if a panic occurs, the entire process will be exited, as there's no valid `T` to put back into the `&mut T`.

Here is the code using `take`:

```
extern crate take_mut;

struct Widget;

impl Widget {
    fn foo(self, rhs: Widget) -> Self {
        self
    }

    fn update(&mut self, rhs: Widget) {
        take_mut::take(self, |s| s.foo(rhs));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it the other way around:

```
impl Widget {
    fn op(mut self, rhs: Widget) -> Self {
        self.update(rhs);
        self
    }

    fn update(&mut self, rhs: Widget) {
        // Some stuff
    }
}
```

You cannot move out of a borrowed pointer, because moving makes the source unusable, but since you don't own the source, that information would have to propagate back to the owner, and Rust doesn't support that.

You might say *"but I'm assigning a new value to `*self` before the function returns!"*. The problem with that is that if there's a panic between the move and the assignment, `*self` would still be left with no valid value. This is especially problematic if dropping `self` is not a no-op (though Rust doesn't care if dropping is a no-op or not here).

Comment: Suppose I can't or don't want to (seeing as this requires a substantially different design and there's no practical reason why the other way shouldn't work just as well).

Comment: That's a good point. I didn't consider what happens if there's a panic.